# Prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to figure out the prime ideals of these rings: $C:=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $R:=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$.

What I know is: any prime ideal of $C$ must contain $I:=(x-i)/(x^2+1)$ or $J:=(x+i)/(x^2+1)$, which are maximal because $C/I\simeq \mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i)\simeq \mathbb{C}\simeq C/J$, and $\mathbb{C}$ is a field. Then $I$ and $J$ are the *only* prime and maximal ideals of $C$, since $(0)$ is not prime here.

> Is this correct?

And also I want to know:

> Is there a unit in $C$?

Now $R$ is confusing me, I know $x^2+1$ is irreducible, then $(x^2+1)$ is prime in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $(0)$ is prime in $R$. More questions appeared:

> Is $\mathbb{R}[x]$ a PID? If yes, then I can conclude $(0)$ is the only prime ideal of $R$, right?

And also:

> Is it true that $R\simeq\mathbb{C}$?

I tried setting $\phi:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $\phi (p(x))=p(i)$, but I got confused trying to convince myself that $\ker(\phi) = (x^2+1)$.

Comment: Yes, $R \simeq \mathbb{C}$. That $(x^2+1) \subset \ker \phi$ is clear, isn't it? Conversely, if $p\in \ker \phi$, i.e. $p(i) = 0$, use the fact that the coefficients are real to conclude that also $p(-i) = 0$. Hence $(x-i) \mid p$ and also $(x+i) \mid p$.

Comment: $F[x]$ is a PID for *any* field $F$, Leo.

Comment: Thanks, guys! It was pretty simple, but you clarified it to me.

Comment: Hint: $R \cong \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Is $x+(x^2+1)$ also  a maximal ideal of $C$,

Comment: Will $C$ be  a 2 dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct about $C$. As for the unit, when you have a ring $R$ with a unit $1$, and an ideal $I$, then $R/I$ is also a ring with a unit, $1+I$.

Now for $R$, it's easy to see that your mapping is well defined, and also a ring homomorphism. Moreover, it's surjective: for every $α+βi$, $α, β$ real, there is $p(x)=α+βx\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $φ(p(x))=α+βi$.

It remains to show that $\ker φ=(x^2+1)$. Obviously, $(x^2+1)$ is a subset of $\ker φ$.  Moreover,  $0\in\ker φ$, while every other real number does not belong to the kernel. Nor do real polynomials of degree $1$, since that would mean they have $i$ as a root. So now let's take a polynomial $p(x)\in
\ker φ$, $\deg p(x)\ge 2$. Then the division algorithm would imply $p(x)=(x^2+1)π(x)+r(x)$, with $\deg r(x)<2$ or $r(x)=0$. But then we should have $p(i)=0$ or $r(i)=0$, which holds if and only if $r(x)=0$. This shows that $p(x)\in (x^2+1)$ or $\ker φ$ is a subset of $(x^2+1)$. This concludes the proof that $\ker φ=(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I liked it because, although your proof is longer than Daniel's, you didn't need to extend the ring and say that $(x-i),(x+i) \in Ker \phi$. I'm sorry, by unit I meant and invertible element

Comment: You are welcome. As for the invertible elements, the above show that both $R$ and $C$ are fields. Every element other than zero of a field is invertible.

Comment: I got why R is a field, but C isn't, right?

Comment: No, $C$ is not field, since $x^2+1$ is reducible